# Can't launch cocos2dx ios project in android

Tags: android, c++, ios, eclipse, xcode

I've had Cocos2dx project which was created in Xcode. In Xcode it's working fine, but now I need to make it work in Eclipse on Android device.

By the way, Eclipse is totally working with Xcode, I've created test project, made couple of changes, everything is fine. But when I've tried to compile my ios project, I've had couple of errors. Here is the log:

> make.exe: *** No rule to make target
>   `jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp', needed by`
>   obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos2dcpp_shared/__/__/Classes/HelloWorldScene.o'.
>   Stop. make.exe: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs...

Very weird error, because I don't have any `HelloWorldScene.cpp` file! But it's not all problems:

> jni/../../Classes/GameManager.h:11:10: fatal error:
>   'cocosbuilder/CCBReader.h' file not found

And another one:

> make.exe: ***
>   [obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos2dcpp_shared/**/**/Classes/AppDelegate.o]
>   Error 1

Guys, please help me out. I was trying to change `Android.mk` file, with no success. Maybe I did something wrong??

Answer (score 5):

You should open file `Android.mk` in folder `proj.android/jni` and update `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` attribute to CPP files, maybe it contains the link to not existing file `../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp`.

Answer (score 3):

The

> proj.android/jni/Android.mk

file might not be properly configured, 
replace this:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes
```

with this:

```
CPP_FILES := $(shell find $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes -name *.cpp)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(CPP_FILES:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(shell find $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes -type d)
```

by doing this it will automatically add all .cpp files within the "Classes" folder.